# cb() never called error while installing angular/cli

Tags: angular

while an installation of angular by `npm install -g @angular/cli` to get an error:

Error at angular/cli installation:

> npm ERR! cb() never called!
>
> npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
>
> npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

I have installed the followings software requirements on to my PC:

```
node -v 
v8.11.2
npm -v
v5.6.0
windows version 8 pro
angular/cli installed by npm install -g @angular/cli
```

please check the screen shot also.

[angular-cli installation error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEROP.png)

**Solution**

we have to do the following things

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g rxjs
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: no need to add angular-cli path. remove that uninstall the angular cli and install it again

Comment: Thanks @TheParam - may I know why dont need to add the angular-cli path? already I have added this path and run the application in angular 6. but now am using angular 7. is this because of version ?

Comment: you no need to set environment variable path or anything. When you insalled nodejs it will give it's command prompt, by using that you us "ng" command, without any settings.

Comment: is what's seen on the screenshot the entire content of your PATH variable? you might've accidentally deleted what's in there when adding your entry. There should be an entry pointing to %AppData%/npm. Entries in PATH are separated by semicolon

Comment: when installing nodejs itself that path added... so no issue with path.. but am getting error like cb() never called in node itself while installing angular/cli

Answer (score 0):

Use this command

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score -3):

cb() never called! **Solved!**

> ```
> Please Don't use sudo to install node, npm and packages!
> ```

### Downloading and installing Node.js and npm

To publish and install packages to and from the public npm registry or your company’s npm Enterprise registry, you must install Node.js and the npm command line interface using either a Node version manager or a Node installer. We strongly recommend using a Node version manager to install Node.js and npm. We do not recommend using a Node installer, since the Node installation process installs npm in a directory with local permissions and can cause permissions errors when you run npm packages globally.

**Official NPM Docs** 
https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm

**Official NVM repository**
https://github.com/creationix/nvm